# Razor tag inside Html.Raw(...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, render

Is it possible to render Razor in `Html.Raw()`? I have a dynamic page being generated that uses the `Html.Raw()` method to render the page that is created in the controller. My raw html has razor tags in it. That is, I am trying to generate a link by

```
@Html.Raw(Model.myRawHtmlContainingRazorTags);
```

where `Model.myRawHtmlContainingRazorTags` contains

```
<html>
...
...
@Model.TheLink
...
...
<html>
```

I need the value of `Model.TheLink`to be rendered when `@Html.Raw(Model.myRawHtmlContainingRazorTags)` is called within the cshtml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have some architectural issues that lead you to have some razor code on your Model property.

Anyway, you can do it by using some external libs such [RazorTemplates](https://github.com/volkovku/RazorTemplates).

Here is a sample :

```
var template = Template.Compile(Model.myRawHtmlContainingRazorTags);
@Html.Raw(template.Render(Model));
```

Comment: I have an API which generates raw HTML list. Clicking on an item in the list, redirects the page with certain arguments. There arguments are fetched from the current HTML page. The arguments are present as hidden fields in the current HTML. The API is called and the raw HTML is assigned to a model. This model is then passed to the view. Now the items in the list have a razor content again, which caused this issue to arise. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what seems unusual for me is that your API generates raw HTML which contains Razor Tag. If you can change it to deliver view name instead of raw html, it will be easier to render with tools like RenderPartial.